# How to access a control templace in code behind?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm a little new Windows Phone developer and I have a lot of questions. My problem at this time is like this:

I have this code:

```
<Button x:Name="InfoEllipse" 
                Foreground="White"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"   
                Margin="0,0,25,0" 
                MinWidth="34" MinHeight="31" 
                   Click="InfoEllipse_Click">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate x:Name="EllipseControlTemplate">
                    <Border x:Name="EllipseButtonBorder"
                            BorderBrush="#4387C4" 
                        Background="#4387C4" 
                        CornerRadius="20,20,20,20"
                            BorderThickness="2">
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```

All this code is placed in a UserControl xaml. My problem is that I want to access my Border -> 'EllipseButtonBorder' in code behind so that when I click on this button to change this border background. Problem is I can't figure out how to access this `EllipseButtonBorder` in code behind? Please some help. I am using Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `VisualState` to manage the states of button.

```
<Button x:Name="InfoEllipse" 
    Foreground="White"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"   
    Margin="0,0,25,0" 
    MinWidth="34" MinHeight="31" 
    Click="InfoEllipse_Click">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate x:Name="EllipseControlTemplate">
            <Border x:Name="EllipseButtonBorder"
                BorderBrush="#4387C4" 
                Background="#4387C4" 
                CornerRadius="20,20,20,20"
                BorderThickness="2">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="EllipseButtonBorder">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Green"/>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: So 'VisualState' is the answer. Great, but I want that color, green for your example, to remain. It is possible with this solution?